# Error 302 when the default page is changed in IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, iis-8

I have the following scenario. I have a website in IIS 8 and I am trying to secure it (https). I have made the web with web forms. In the process to secure it I have to change the page at the beginning (default page in the IIS administrator). When I do it, I don't get the change and I go to the website that was set by default.
I have seen the log and when trying to access the new homepage it gives an error 302 (object moved). I have seen the response header and I see that the location is configured with the old home page.
Example:
Old default page: www.namedomain.com/start.aspx
New default page: www. namedomain.com/home.aspx
The new website has as in the response header: location = /start.aspx and as I said before when trying to access it gives error 302.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things going on here, "securing" the site with HTTPS and also potentially `<authentication mode="Forms">` in your web.config where it will try and redirect any unauthorised requests to a login page. It seems like you are just doing the HTTPS though at this stage, and maybe trying to set up a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS?

It sounds like you are also trying to change the default page for the website (in IIS or the web.config?) from default.aspx to home.aspx? I'm not sure I understand why you want to do that as it isn't necessary for HTTPS, but the effect of that will mean you can go to https://www.namedomain.com/ and you will get served the content from home.aspx instead of start.aspx (or default.aspx) **but the URL will stay as just https://www.namedomain.com/**

Normally to set up HTTPS, all you do is go into IIS, Bindings, and add a HTTPS binding (you'll need a TLS certificate to make the https work properly). then just make sure you include the "https://" at the start of your URL.

If you think it might be caching problem on your machine, just add a nonsense querystring to the end of your URL (like https://www.namedomain.com?blah=blahblah) and it will cause your browser to get a fresh copy of the page.

I'm not sure what is causing the 302 redirect, have you added any special code to swap HTTP requests over to HTTPS? Can you update your answer with any more info?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your interest, I indicate the information you request:
Authentication is integrated into windows with domain user.
I am doing the HTTPS configuration through the IIS manager.
The page change is because the old one (in the example /start.aspx) is no longer appropriate to be displayed and you have to go directly to /home.aspx.

Comment: OK, I recommend breaking it into two separate problems, forget the HTTPS for now, get the new default page redirect working with just HTTP (this sounds like the main problem), then work on the HTTPS securing after that. Can you go directly to /home.aspx or not? In IIS default pages is home.aspx at the top of the list? (needs to be higher than others to work)

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried to make the default page change in HTTP but the same thing happens to me. When you try to load the web /home.aspx it does not and load /start.aspx. I have verified the response header and the same thing happens with https, because it appears configured /start.aspx.

Comment: So you can’t access home.aspx even directly? Possible places I can think of for redirects are code behind, web.config, global.asax.cs, something is causing that redirect, if you can find out what it is, I can help further

Comment: I have observed that in the section of administration of page by default, if I give the option "Revert to primary" I get the old one (/start.aspx). I have to think that the problem is there, somewhere else that page is configured as primary.

Comment: It doesn't let me access /home.aspx. It always redirects me to the old one (/start.aspx). I have reviewed webconfig and it is correct.

Comment: I already found the problem. Due to the code adaptation that I had to do, an assignment to a session variable (Session.add) was not being made. Once this is done, the web by default loads well. Thanks for the interest Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is what I put in my last comment Jalpa.  I do not understand very well the relationship between not configuring the session variables and the default page but once corrected in code, the application correctly loads the web by default.